# Bootstrap padding BG colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my webpage http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/company.html

As you can see, there are 2 grey boxes on top. I do not want the gap in between them. I want it to be combined into 1 rectangle box.

They are both in different columns the left one is col-8 and the right one os col-4. When i checked in the browser, it seems there is a 15px padding each between them.

I am ok with the padding but can the padding also have the same BG colour ? Then that will solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: padding always shows the same bg-color

Comment: What you can do is add a row and cut out the entire content for the grey part from the columns and add it in col-md-12

Comment: use those two columns in one `col-md-12` and using add one more class and overwrite that padding of internal col-md. Give br color to this col-md-12 div (use another class for bg color)

Comment: Why is there a gap between the 2 boxes?

Comment: .our_company{margin-right:-15px}  and , ..our_leader{margin-left:-15px} will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

Seperate grey part into another row and you are good to go.

```
 <div class="row">
         <div class="our_company col-sm-8">
                             <h2>Our Company</h2><br>

                            <p>As the name indicates, Element Design Studio is a boutique design studio that provides landscape master planning and full serviced landscape architecture services for hotels, resorts, residential developments, mixed-use projects and golf course landscapes. Headquartered in Singapore, Element was co-founded by Gregory Kunak in 2011 based on simple and straightforward fundamentals; to provide Clients with the highest quality design services.<br><br>
                    Since 2011, Element has provided design services for a vast amount of projects located in 16 countries, consisting of Bangladesh, Egypt, Guinea, India, Indonesia, Laos, Kenya, Korea, Malaysia, Mauritius, Nepal, Saudi Arabia, Seychelles, Singapore, Sri Lanka and Vietnam. <br><br>
                                Whether appointed to provide landscape master planning services on a 100 hectare mixed-use development or engaged to provide detailed landscape design services for a hotel, resort or luxury residential condominium, Element takes immense pride with providing the highest quality of design excellence throughout every stage of the project. Above all, it is our fundamental goal to ensure that our Clients achieve a successful landscape product.</p><br>

                            </div><div class="our_leader col-sm-4">
                        <h2>Our Leadership</h2><br>

                        Gregory Kunak<br>
                        <h3>Managing Director</h3>
                                 <img src="image/Gregory-Kunak-Profile.jpg">
                                <p>After working for 20 years with two of the largest and most prominent landscape architecture firms in the United States and Singapore, Gregory Kunak co-founded Element in 2011.<br><br>  Through his career, Gregory has gained extensive design experience on many notable hotels, resorts, residential developments and mixed-use projects throughout the United States, Caribbean, Middle East and majority of Asia. As Managing Director of Element, Gregory is responsible for every aspect of the company.<br><br> As a registered landscape architect, Gregory is responsible for ensuring that each and every project adheres to the most stringent health, safety and welfare standards while striving to achieve design excellence.  He is a rollercoaster enthusiast, enjoys the outdoors and horticulture and supports the Pittsburgh Steelers. </p></div>

      </div>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
You need to make change in you `div`

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 bg-grey">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         This is col 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         This is col 2
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.bg-grey {
   background-color: grey;
}
```